# How to store string as html code in php?

Tags: php, html, string

Please guide me how I can store a string of written html or html mixed with php code in a php file?

For example i want to a add html code by php file function, how I have to store string that will be displayed in my new html file.

Comment: your question is unclear?

Comment: do you have a loose example of what you are aiming for?

Comment: Its a bit unclear what you are asking, do you want to write a file containing HTML to disk? Store it in a database? Edit your question so that it is apparent what you want to do.

Comment: Please specify `store string as a html tags and codes in a php file?` what it means? also `i want to a example html file by php file function` what you want to say here?

Comment: http://Stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for.

```
 <?php

    $divId = 'main_div';

    echo myfun($divId);

    function myfun($divId ){
        $html = "<div id='".$divId."'> This is a html div </div>";
        $html .= "<input type='text' value='".$divId."'>";
        return $html;
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

just like a normal string:

```
$htmlSnippet = "<div id=\"yourID\">the content of your div</div>";
```

or you can use single quotes:

```
$htmlSnippet = '<div id="yourID">the content of your div</div>';
```

Comment: Already tried this one. But that was too long and have &lt;?php &gt; inside that.

Comment: You can't have php tags inside a string... (Or do you want to display php code as readable text?)